# Associate an application with a file extension on Windows 7 + Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi

Hello How do I code about Delphi
http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2001/a/bltip0801_3.htm
Running on Windows 7.
Because this code only works on windows XP
Thank you, Good Morning

Comment: Please don't ask questions here by posting  links to somewhere else and asking "How do I make this work in something else?" You're expecting us to go somewhere else to even figure out what your question is, and if that other link moves or is off-line your question becomes useless to future readers here. If you have a question, include the **relevant** code right here in your question.

Answer (score 4):

The shown code will work, you just need elevated rights to write to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.
Run as administrator or add an appropriate manifest to yout Application.

Comment: Or do it properly on Win7, which is by writing to HKCU instead, unless you're doing an install and want to register the extension for all users of the machine (which means you should already be running the install as an Admin).